# write function in R

Tags: r

I'm using the write function right now in R with a matrix, and this is what I have

```
write(my_mtx,file='mtx.tsv',sep='\t')
```

But this gives me a file with one column? I've also tried adding an 'ncolumns' argument

```
write(mt_mtx,ncolumns=length(colnames(my_mtx)),file='mtx.tsv',sep='\t')
```

But this just gives me a repeat of the one columns as opposed to actual separated columns as it appears in the matrix. a little help?

Comment: What are the  dimensions of `my_mtx`? (what is `my_mtx`?)

Answer (score 6):

Try using `write.table` instead

```
write.table(mt_mtx, file = 'mtx.tsv', sep ='\t', col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

Then it will default to the correct number of columns and there is no need to transpose

Answer (score 1):

default for `write()` is one column if the data are character, five columns if the data are numeric, and it fills by rows (see `?write`).  Try this:

```
write(t(my_mtx),file='mx.tsv',sep='\t',ncolumns=ncol(my_mtx))
```